# Need to see if a range contains any items from a list in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a list of names. Then I have a row with several hundred entries, some of which include those names. Using IF I would like to return whether or not one of the items in that list is in the row.

=if(a1:a500=list_name,1,2)

In spite of the fact that there are items from the list in that range always comes up "2". If I put in a single item from that that list as the logical test it works, but not when I put the list as the test.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot compare values in two ranges like this. It is better that you use VLOOKUP to check values in the list_name in range A1:A500

Answer (score 0):

YOU NEED TO USE VLOOKUP FUNCTION OR INDEX/MATCH FUNCTION .
POST A STRUCTURE OF YOUR TABLES

LIKE: =VLOOKUP('NAME',a1:a500,FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

From your sample formula, it looks like your list's cell range has been assigned a name; e.g. *list_name*. You can reiterate through the list on a `COUNTIF` function if you use a `SUMPRODUCT` wrapping function to provide array processing. In the following, I've put my criteria list into Z2:Z5 and named it *list_name*.

[image]

The formula for a strict count in A8 is

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:A6, list_name))`

The `SIGN` of a number will be *-1, 0* or *1*. If you subtract the `SIGN` of the count produced by `SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(...))` from *2* then you should get the *1* or *2* that your sample formula was trying to return. In A9 as,

`=2-SIGN(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:A6, list_name)))`

Fill both cells right as necessary.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped, however the point wasn't to get 1, but rather to have it validate to true. I apologize, I'm still learning how to ask questions as effectively as possible.

Comment: By at least one definition, a `False` is zero and anything that is not `False` is `True`. If we go by that then `=AND(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:A6, list_name)))` will return either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
=IF(COUNTIF(row_old_list,name_new_list)>=1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

If, for example, you have a list of old names from A1:ZZ1, and a name you want to check in cell A3, and more names right under it, try this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$ZZ$1,A3),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Should give you True/False values.